# Find $f=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n$ st. $f_{n+1}(x)=pf_n(x)+\frac{1-p}{2}(f_n(x+1)+f_n(x-1))$ and $f_0(0)=1$ and $f_0(x)=0$ for $x\neq 0$.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose I start a population density concentrated at $x=0$, so that

$$ f_0(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x = 0 \\
0 & \text{if } x \neq 0
\end{cases} $$

Then, each time step, the population either stays home with probability $p\in[0,1]$ or moves to a neighboring vertex with equal probability. Therefore the recurrence is given by

$$f_{n+1}(x)=pf_n(x)+\frac{1-p}{2}(f_n(x+1)+f_n(x-1)) \tag{1}$$

> How can I calculate the limiting distribution $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$?

My expectation is that it is some form of binomial distribution or Gaussian distribution, however neither seems sufficient, since binomial has compact support and Gaussian has continuous support.

---

**Attempt.** Perhaps we should look for a fixed point of the iteration, which satisfies

$$f(x)=pf(x)+\frac{1-p}{2}(f(x+1)+f(x-1)) \tag{2}$$

Then

$$(1-p)f(x)=\frac{1-p}{2}(f(x+1)+f(x-1))$$

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}(f(x+1)+f(x-1)) \tag{3}$$

So $f$ is the average of its neighbors... that is satisfied by constant functions, but those are not a valid distribution and not what I expected... Are there more solutions to $(3)$ than the constant solution?

Comment: every linear function $f(x)=ax+b$, $a,b\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $p=1,$ we have $f_n=f_0$ for all $n,$ so $f=f_0$.

For $p<1,$ then **if the limit exists**, your argument applies to show $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}(f(x-1)+f(x+1)).$  This means $f$ is linear as a function on the integers, but since $f_n$ are non-negative, $f$ must be a non-negative constant.  Also since $\sum_{x\in\mathbb{Z}} f_n(x) = 1$ for all $n$ we can see (e.g. via Fatou's lemma) $f=0.$

Comment: I don't currently have a good argument for the existence of the limit, but that's the only hole in the argument.

Comment: You're right, $f$ converges to zero. However if the random walk terminates upon "staying home" then the distribution is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}p(1-p)^nf_n(x)$ which is nonzero. Thanks!